# devise send mails, overwrite default :from option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

In my mailer.rb file at the top i have written

```
default :from => "a@b.com"
```

and i have my functions below this line, for ex:

```
def insurance
  .....
end

def welcome
  .....
end
```

for insurance action mail should go from ins@b.com and for welcome inf@b.com,

how can i override this default from, how to write inside each function.

Is there any option like that available except?

I tried default from with except [:actionname] also tried, mail(:from , :to,...) inside action, default from id is been taken

Comment: `mail(from: 'foo')` will override the `default from:`

Comment: please explain your question correctly. it is poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#edit-the-mailer), it clearly states `default Hash - This is a hash of default values for any email you send from this mailer. This can be overridden on a per-email basis.`

So answer to your question is yes you simply need to specify from or to option inside your mailer method to override your default from or to options specified above. Inside your method you can do:

```
def insurance
  mail( from: ins@b.com, to: inf@b.com, subject: 'Your subject')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default :from => "a@b.com"
```

This must override default:

```
def insurance
 mail(from: "ins@b.com",to: @user.email, subject: 'Insurance .. ')
end

def welcome
 mail(from: "inf@b.com",to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome .. ')
end
```